# Join tables with distinct highest ranked row

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have three tables defined like this:

```
[tbMember]
memberID | memberName
1        | John
2        | Peter

[tbGroup] 
groupID | groupName
1       | Alpha
2       | Beta
3       | Gamma    

[tbMemberGroupRelation]
memberID | groupID | memberRank (larger number is higher)
1        | 1       | 0
1        | 2       | 1
2        | 1       | 5
2        | 2       | 3
2        | 3       | 1
```

And now I want to perform a table-join selection to get result which contains (distinct) member with his highest ranked group in each row, for the given example above, the query result is desired to be:

```
memberID | memberName | groupName | memberRank
1        | John       | Beta      | 1
2        | Peter      | Alpha     | 5
```

Is there a way to implement it in a single SQL like following style ?

```
select * from tbMember m
    left join tbMemberGroupRelation mg on (m.MemberID = mg.MemberID and ......)
    left join tbGroup g on (mg.GroupID = g.GroupID)
```

Any other solutions are also appreciated if it is impossible to write in a simple query.

> ========= UPDATED =========
>
> Only ONE highest rank is allowed in table

Comment: What if the member has equal ranks for two different groups?

Comment: Only 1 highest rank is allowed. Updated in my original post. @TomH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method:

```
SELECT
    M.memberID,
    M.memberName,
    G.groupName,
    MG.memberRank
FROM
    Member M
LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberGroup MG ON MG.memberID = M.memberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberGroup MG2 ON
        MG2.memberID = M.memberID AND
        MG2.memberRank > MG.memberRank
INNER JOIN [Group] G ON G.groupid = MG.groupid
WHERE
    MG2.memberid IS NULL
```

Might perform better in some situations due to indexing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to create an inverted sequence/rank of the `memberRank` so that the highest rank per member is always equal to 1.

This is how I achieved it using a sub-query:

```
SELECT
    m.memberID,
    m.memberName,
    g.groupName,
    mg.memberRank
FROM
    tbMember m
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        memberID,
        groupID,
        groupName,
        memberRank,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY memberID ORDER BY memberRank DESC) AS invRank
    FROM
        tbMemberGroupRelation
    ) mg
    ON (mg.memberID = m.memberID)
    AND (mg.invRank = 1)
LEFT JOIN
    tbGroup g
    ON (g.groupID = mg.groupID);
```

Comment: It works and has good performance when selecting from huge quantities of data.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table [tbGroup] (groupid int, groupname varchar(8000))
Insert [tbGroup] Values (1, 'Alpha')
Insert [tbGroup] Values (2, 'Beta')
Insert [tbGroup] Values (3, 'Gamma')

create table [tbMemberGroupRelation] (memberid int, groupid int, memberrank int)
Insert [tbMemberGroupRelation] Values (1,1,0)
Insert [tbMemberGroupRelation] Values (1,2,1)
Insert [tbMemberGroupRelation] Values (2,1,5)
Insert [tbMemberGroupRelation] Values (2,2,3)
Insert [tbMemberGroupRelation] Values (2,3,1)

;With cteMemberGroupRelation As
(
Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By MemberID Order By MemberRank Desc) SortOrder
    From [tbMemberGroupRelation]
)
 Select *
    From tbMember M
    Join (Select * From cteMemberGroupRelation Where SortOrder = 1) R On R.memberid = M.memberid
    Join tbGroup G On G.groupid = R.groupid
```